# I want to design this Navigation Bar in flutter but can't manage to round border and place floating button in centre like the image below

Tags: flutter, mobile

Can anyone help with this ?
[Navigatioon Bar Reuired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frjy7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect Solution:https://stackoverflow.com/a/72406315/16434562

**Note**: This is not my creation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this package. [animated_bottom_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_bottom_navigation_bar)

Answer (score 0):

add this package in `animated_bottom_navigation_bar: ^0.3.3` in `pubspec.yaml`
then add below code then run customize

```
Scaffold(
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      //params
   ),
   floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
   bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
      icons: iconList,
      activeIndex: _bottomNavIndex,
      gapLocation: GapLocation.center,
      notchSmoothness: NotchSmoothness.defaultEdge,
      onTap: (index) => setState(() => _bottomNavIndex = index),
      //other params
   ),
);
```