# How to make really Custom BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to design a very custom BottomNavigationBar in flutter like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do this kind of lump/growth in the top center of the bar ?

I precise I don't want a rounded FloatingActionButton, the best result I had with this methode is not exatcly what expected:

[image: https://i.ibb.co/b60FT10/Capture-d-cran-du-2022-05-27-15-27-34.png]

Comment: It's simply a FloatingActionButton notched to a  Bottom Navigation Bar. You can customize the size, color and margin of the button however you want.

Check this guide out: https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/77/how-to-set-notched-floating-action-button-in-bottom-navigation-bar/

Comment: Ok this is pretty that, but not exactly what i'm expected: https://i.ibb.co/b60FT10/Capture-d-cran-du-2022-05-27-15-27-34.png
The round should not start exactly i the middle, but slightly above as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **CustomPaint widget** and **CustomPainter class**, to draw exactly what you need. You can draw a customized path, in your case, using the path.LineTo and path.arcToPoint functions. Then use stack to put your IconButtons where ever you want
.
[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ToqYMSnNhA) explains how you can use custom paint.

**Update**

I added a sample code, you can edit the numbers and achieve what you need. This code will give you the orange widget on this image:

[image]

```
class CustomBottomNav extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomBottomNav({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        CustomPaint(
          size: Size(size.width, 110),
          painter: MyCustomPainter(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.orange
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    Path path = Path()..moveTo(0, 50);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.4, 50);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.5, 5, size.width * 0.6, 50);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 50);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe that should be the only way since other answer don't show exactly what i'm expecting.
But this is the hard way.

Comment: It's because each UI Design has its own specific details, it's really hard to find a piece of code that implements exactly what you have. Learn how to fish then.

Comment: you can use this widget as bottomNavigationBar and add your icons using a Row as a child of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

MyFab Button
**Change size and wrap with ClipOval**

[image]

[image]

For example, you can take a look at my [project](https://github.com/mrasityilmaz/crypto_app).

Comment: This is pretty that, but not exactly what i'm expecting: https://i.ibb.co/b60FT10/Capture-d-cran-du-2022-05-27-15-27-34.png

The round should not start exactly in the horizontal middle, but slightly above as shown above, like an oval.

Comment: I updated,you mean  this.

Answer (score 0):

I have this image and code please  some change and use it.[image]

```
import 'package:fancy_bottom_navigation/fancy_bottom_navigation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyPlugin extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/FancyBottomNavigationPage';

  @override
  _MyPluginState createState() => _MyPluginState();
}

class _MyPluginState extends State<MyPlugin> {
  int currentPage = 0;

  GlobalKey bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
        child: Center(
          child: _getPage(currentPage),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: FancyBottomNavigation(
        tabs: [
          TabData(
            iconData: Icons.home,
            title: "Home",
            onclick: () {},
          ),
          TabData(iconData: Icons.person, title: "Profile"),
          TabData(iconData: Icons.more_vert, title: "More")
        ],
        initialSelection: 1,
        key: bottomNavigationKey,
        onTabChangedListener: (position) {
          setState(
            () {
              currentPage = position;
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _getPage(int page) {
    switch (page) {
      case 0:
        return Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("This is the home page"),
          ],
        );
      case 1:
        return Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("This is the Profile page"),
          ],
        );
      default:
        return Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("This is the More page"),
          ],
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is almost that, but not exactly what i'm expected: https://i.ibb.co/b60FT10/Capture-d-cran-du-2022-05-27-15-27-34.png. The round should not start exactly i the middle, but slightly above as shown above.